# What does 'insert overwrite local directory' mean in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Im having some issues understanding what does the following type of query do:

`insert overwrite local directory $directorey_name$
 select $some_query$`

What does this mean, and what are the side effects of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Export the query results into a file on the local file system

```
insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/hello'
row format delimited
fields terminated by '|'
select 1,2,3,'Hello','world'
;
```

---

```
! ls /tmp/hello;
```

> ```
> 000000_0
> ```

```
! cat /tmp/hello/000000_0;
```

> ```
> 1|2|3|Hello|world
> ```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks. What would you usually use this for?

Comment: The usual I guess... export tables/queries to flat files and feed them to applications/people

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz